# How can I remove wordpress from cpanel

Tags: wordpress

I have installed wordpress in my cpanel and moved the files to public_html folder and when I did that I coudnt access to wordpress login anymore. Now I want to remove and uninstall thatfor re installing that again, What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the whole wordpress folder from public_html ?